# Immediately send redirect response, preserving session data

Tags: php, validation, http, form, laravel

This question is for Laravel 4 only, as the relevant parts are completely refactored in the upcoming Laravel 5.

I have written an helper function for validation, so I only have to put this in controllers:

```
public function postAdd()
{
    validate([
        'foo' => 'required',
        'bar' => 'required',
    ]);

    // process data...
}
```

I love it!

And here is the helper:

```
function validate($rules)
{
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        $request = Request::instance();

        $response = Redirect::to(URL::previous())
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors($validator);

        Session::save();
        $response->send();
        App::terminate($request, $response);
        exit;
    }
}
```

My concerns are mainly about the four last lines. The point is to immediately send the response, otherwise I have to return it from the helper, then handle the helper result (Response|null) in the controller (quite easy, but I want really thin controllers).

I did my best to return this response the more gracefully possible. Session data obviously has to be saved, and possible "finish" callbacks are triggered. But, looking at [`Application`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php)'s `run()` and `getStackedClient()` method, I'm afraid of missing something.

So, am I missing something? Could this code be further improved?

Comment: Just as a reminder, Laravel 5 has simplified [validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation) a lot and makes use of [terminable middlewares](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware#terminable-middleware), so you can simply do `$this->validate(request(), $rules);` in your controller.